# C# Bitmap region is already locked

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing

I need to process a single image very constantly and i use another thread(apart from the main ui) to do it. Actually i get a RGB array and i turn it into a Bitmap-That's the initial first process,after that im getting(from a socket if it's really interest you :P) a smaller array which contains only the changed at certain position,somthing like deltas. I need to apply this rgb array everytime on the initial image and update it according to the rgb component in each array.
This is not my problem now, this stage was done already, my main problem is when i send it to a method which **Lock the bitmap and process it** it throws  An

> Bitmap region is already locked.

Error after few seconds of running.

This is my code:

```
public void retreive()
    {
            byte[] res = decompress( ReceiveVarData(s));//receiving the array.              
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(res);//storing it in a ms.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms);//use binaryreader to read from it.
            Bitmap first = FirstProcess(br);              
            pictureBox1.Image =new Bitmap( first);
          //this is the initial part, the first process.
            current = first;                
           while (true)
            {
                byte[] del = ReceiveVarData(s);                 
               current = DeltaProcessing(del);
                pictureBox1.Image =  current;

            }              
    }

    Bitmap current;
    private unsafe Bitmap DeltaProcessing(byte []rgb)
    {          
      BitmapData  bmData = current.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 1920,1080), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
      IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;

        for (int i=0;i<rgb.Length;i+=7)
        {
            int offset = BitConverter.ToInt32(rgb, i);
                byte* p = (byte*)((int)(scan0) + offset);
                p[0] = rgb[i+4];
                p[1] = rgb[i+5];
                p[2] = rgb[i+6];
                p[3] = 255;

       }

       current.UnlockBits(bmData);
        return current;

    }


      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        tl.Start();
        cl = tl.AcceptTcpClient();
        s = cl.Client;
        Thread th = new Thread(retreive);
        th.Start();
    }
```

As you see,i simply loop to process the image and apply the new rgb values.
As i mentioned before-**this is not the problem** the very odd problem is that i keep getting the `bitmap region is already locked`  error  eventhough i make sure i `Unlock` the bitmap everytime after the process.. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the threading code you mention? If the whole thing is running from another thread, your code would not work since you are manipulating UI on a non-UI thread (`pictureBox1.Image = ...`).

Comment: @Krumelur look i edited my code.

Comment: There are several nasty bugs in this code, exactly how it is going to fail is hard to reason through.  I suspect the real code has try/catch to fail with specific exception.  The PictureBox.Image property is not thread-safe, you cannot assign it from the worker thread.  Your code is not exception-safe.  And this code *will* die with an exception, you'll run out of memory in a few seconds.  Disposing bitmaps you no longer use is not optional.

Comment: @HansPassant alright...i just tried `pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(()=>pictureBox1.Image= current));` but now im getting `object is already in use elsewhere` error... i dont know what to do :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you re-use the `Bitmap` (`current`) holded by `pictureBox1`. When the system tried to paint the image, it is locked inside `DeltaProcessing` function.

Consider using double buffering:

- `Bitmap first` is associated with `pictureBox1`
- `Bitmap current` is *another* Bitmap storing the next image
- The contents from `current` are copied into `first` and `pictureBox1` is invalidated after `current` updated.

Comment: i still dont understand. the paint is done only after  `DeltaProcessing` returns the bitmap. the whole lock process is done before showing it on a picturebox!

Comment: You create a Bitmap only once: `Bitmap first = FirstProcess(br);`

The function `DeltaProcessing` does not create a new Bitmap.

Bitmap is the reference type.

Comment: but i dont want to create everytime infinte instances of  `new Bitmap()..` i dont even need it .. i just process the pixels and apply changed.. i just tried `pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(()=>pictureBox1.Image=  current));` but now im getting `object is already in use elsewhere error..` please you must help me :)

Comment: You wouldn't need an infinite number of instances, just two.

Comment: @Krumelur alright.. suppose i've created new instance `Bitmap current=new Bitmap(1920,1080);`. what now?  i would very appreicate if you can post your answer :)

Comment: Try something like that `using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(first)) { G.DrawImage(current, 0, 0); } pictureBox1.Repaint();`

Comment: @AndreyNasonov never heard about this `pictureBox1.Repaint()`

Comment: Repaint() paints immediately.

Comment: Sorry, the correct name is `Refresh()`, not `Repaint()`.